# BizTalk splitting stored procedure result

Tags: wcf, biztalk, biztalk-2013

When I call a stored procedure from BizTalk the result is split across multiple nodes. The stored procedure returns XML which is mangled by being split.

Multiple sources state the correct configuration will automatically assemble the result but I'm not able to make it work.

Example result:

```
<bsp_FA_StatementOutputResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedProcedures/dbo">
  <StoredProcedureResultSet0>
    <StoredProcedureResultSet0 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/ProceduresResultSets/dbo/bsp_FA_StatementOutput">
      <XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B>&lt;Root...</XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B>
      </StoredProcedureResultSet0>
    <StoredProcedureResultSet0 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/ProceduresResultSets/dbo/bsp_FA_StatementOutput">
      <XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B>...</XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B>
    </StoredProcedureResultSet0>
    <StoredProcedureResultSet0 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/ProceduresResultSets/dbo/bsp_FA_StatementOutput">
      <XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B>sactionDate&gt;2020-10-6&lt;/...;&lt;/Root&gt;</XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B>
    </StoredProcedureResultSet0>
  </StoredProcedureResultSet0>
  <ReturnValue>0</ReturnValue>
</bsp_FA_StatementOutputResponse>
```

The stored procedure works correctly when executed manually.

- I created the send port using the 'Add generated items' wizard.
- I chose 'strongly typed' from the wizard.
- I used the bindings provided by the wizard.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So you have stored XML in a column and you are trying to return that in a stored procedure?    Can you show us your stored procedure and the structure of your table?    It is probably more of a SQL question in how to format it as the XML structure you want in the stored procedure as all the BizTalk SQL adapter is doing is escaping the XML from your result set and having multiple rows.  Can you also show your results from when you execute it manually.

Comment: I believe you've completely misunderstood. The issue is the result in the node named 'XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B" is chopped up into two pieces. It's the XML result from the sproc. XML randomly chopped into bits doesn't parse very well ;)  I suspect the issue is the WCF transport layer is doing it

Comment: The result in sql server management studio has the correct result and returns correctly formed XML. This page claims a solution but I was unable to make it work since I am not using xmlpolling. https://www.reply.com/solidsoft-reply/en/content/biztalk-101-how-to-consume-a-complex-sql-stored-procedure-xml-response-without-a-custom-pipeline

Comment: So why aren't you using XmlPolling as per the article?   You also need to specify the XmlStoredProcedureRootnodename and XmlStoredProcedureRootnodenamespace as per that article.   I don't think the Wizard is going to help you with this scenario.  You have to configure things manually, and probably also generate the schema from the XML rather than via the Consume Adapter Wizard.

Comment: This process runs monthly at a scheduled time. Polling is not a good design choice.

Comment: You are confusing having a Receive Poling port with a Send Port configured with XmlPolling.  Even that article is talking about a Send port.  Follow the instructions in that blog

Comment: I tried many combinations of polling modes, root node names, and namespaces. None worked so I posted my question here. I've since found a relatively simple way to assemble the result set in the orchestration. I'll post an answer once I'm not so slammed at work. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've had this issue I've documented the solution I came up with [here](https://jaysprenkle.wordpress.com/2021/04/12/biztalk-two-way-send-port-breaks-xml-returned-from-sqlserver/). I used a manual XSLT map to reassemble the fragmented result.

Comment: This is actually not the optimal solution. The initial commentary that BizTalk/WCF would reassemble the result set is correct but there are many non obvious requirements

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I misunderstood first, see below.

If you don't want to split resultsets from a stored procedure, just remove the `is_enelope="yes"` from the typed procedure schema.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this applies. My question was how to join the parts of the result from SQL server into a single (correct) xml document. You mention the 'disassemble' stage and selecting a single result of many. I can see that might be useful if the sproc was returning multiple result sets, but that's not the problem. It was splitting a single result set and mangling the xml.

Comment: Sorry, I must have misread your problem ‍♂️ If you don't want to split, just remove the is_enelope="yes" from the typed procedure schema.